# Are there Windows 7 keyboard shortcuts for Log Off and Standby?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, standby, logoff

I like the Windows-L keyboard shortcut to lock the computer. Are there similar shortcuts for "Log Off" and "Standby"? Is it possible to remap Windows-L to a different function?

Comment: They better would **not** exist, since these are highly destructive actions.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

With an [**AutoHotkey**](http://www.autohotkey.com/) script, you can remap the <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> shortcut and create another one for Sleep (I chose <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, normally not used unless you use OneNote):

```
#l::         ; Win+L
Shutdown, 0  ; this is the code for Log Off
return

#s::         ; Win+S
DllCall("PowrProf\SetSuspendState", "int", 0, "int", 0, "int", 0) ; DLL call to sleep
return
```

There is more detail on the DLL call in AutoHotkey's help file:

```
; Call the Windows API function "SetSuspendState" to have the system suspend or hibernate.
; Windows 95/NT4: Since this function does not exist, the following call would have no effect.
; Parameter #1: Pass 1 instead of 0 to hibernate rather than suspend.
; Parameter #2: Pass 1 instead of 0 to suspend immediately rather than asking each application for permission.
; Parameter #3: Pass 1 instead of 0 to disable all wake events.
DllCall("PowrProf\SetSuspendState", "int", 0, "int", 0, "int", 0)
```

Comment: Note that **AutoHotKey_L** is now the main development branch. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoHotkey and http://l.autohotkey.net/

Answer (score 26):

## Standby

- create a new text file and put this on it

> rundll32 powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState

- save it as "standby.bat" and create a shortcut of it on the desktop
- right-click the shortcut, select **propriety** and edit its *shortcut key* to **CTRL + ALT + S**

now  <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> will put your computer in standby.

## Logoff

- create a new text file and put this on it

> logoff

- save it as "logoff.bat" and create a shortcut of it on the desktop
- right-click the shortcut, select **propriety** and edit its *shortcut key* to **CTRL + ALT + L**

now <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> will logoff.

Comment: Do shortcuts' Shortcut keys actually work now?  Unpossible!  I gave up trying to use those back in Win95. :)

Comment: You don't really need to create a batch file; you can create a shortcut directly to the `logoff` executable.

Comment: +1 because it is a solution that doesn't involve installing another (albeit flexible) program just to do one thing.

Comment: @intuited is right. I did both ways. I'm in Windows 8.1. The batch method needs administrator priviledges every time you hit the shortcut to run. By having a shortcut of the logoff executable directly to desktop you can CTRL + ALT + L without a prompt. Much better that way.

Answer (score 13):

The Windows 7 hibernate shortcut key is more like a PlayStation secret function!

<kbd>⊞ Win</kbd>, <kbd>→</kbd>, <kbd>→</kbd>, then:

- <kbd>H</kbd> - hibernate
- <kbd>S</kbd> - sleep
- <kbd>U</kbd> - shutdown
- <kbd>O</kbd> - lock
- <kbd>L</kbd> - log off

It helps when you have lost your screen on the way! An alternative shortcut to hibernate is:

<kbd>⊞ Win</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd>, <kbd>H</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: Though technically "win, ->, ->, s" isn't a real short cut, as you're just navigating to the sleep button via your keyboard :\

Comment: You're right Bob. They are not short-cuts. My screen blacks out when I connect to the PC remotely, and never comes back. I use a keyborad Sleep button to sleep the PC and then bring it back, and its fine. But if I didn't have that (or the screen is locked), there does not seem to be a key-code to reproduce the same thing.

Comment: didnt know about the WIN+D, Alt+F4. tnx. p.s.WIN+rightArrow, moves my windows to the right - oops, you mean win , let go, then right arrow twice. got it!

Answer (score 5):

There is a keyboard solution using existing shortcuts, though not as a single chord (meaning release each key before pressing the next):

- <kbd>Win</kbd>, <kbd>→</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd> - last used shutdown action
- <kbd>Win</kbd>, <kbd>→</kbd>, <kbd>→</kbd> - select shutdown action

Found it at https://superuser.com/questions/16327/what-are-your-favourite-less-well-known-keyboard-shortcuts-in-windows

Answer (score 2):

You can use the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> shortcut then choose what you want in the resulting dialog box, or you can make one of them your default by doing the following:

- Click on the start button
- Right click on the arrow beside the bottom Power Settings button, and choose the Properties in this context menu. It should be the only one.
- In that dialog box choose Sleep (or whatever default you want) in the Power button Action field, then apply it and click OK.

When you're ready to put your PC to sleep or whatever you chose, use the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> keyboard shortcut and then hit Enter. Whatever you set in the first step will be the default action that is applied when you hit Enter.

Answer (score 1):

This tutorial is for Windows Vista, but should work also for Windows 7.

[Vista Log Off Shortcut Creation](http://www.vistax64.com/tutorials/73998-log-off.html)

Answer (score 1):

This should really help out: [Windows 7 Keyboard Shortcuts / Windows / Keyboard-Shortcut.com](http://www.keyboard-shortcut.com/windows/windows-7-keyboard-shortcuts.php)

Shutdown is actually <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>→</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

create a shortcut
inside run

```
shutdown /l
```

then

```
set to shortcut key to  WIN+ALT+L
```

done

Answer (score 0):

Win + R "shutdown /L", the command line log off which can also be used as shortcut icon with custom user shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

#### Shortcut for logging out (Win 10/8/7/Vista)

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>, followed by <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.

#### All Ctrl+Alt+Delete shortcuts

- After opening screen with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>:

  - **Lock this computer**: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>
  - **Switch Users**: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>
  - **Log off**: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>
  - **Change a password...**: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
  - **Start Task Manage**r: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

[image: Ctrl+Alt+Delete screen]

Answer (score 0):

#l::         ; Win+L
Shutdown, 0  ; this is the code for Log Off
return

#s::         ; Win+S
DllCall("PowrProf\SetSuspendState", "int", 0, "int", 0, "int", 0) ; DLL call to sleep
return
There is more detail on the DLL call in AutoHotkey's help file:

; Call the Windows API function "SetSuspendState" to have the system suspend or hibernate.
; Windows 95/NT4: Since this function does not exist, the following call would have no effect.
; Parameter #1: Pass 1 instead of 0 to hibernate rather than suspend.
; Parameter #2: Pass 1 instead of 0 to suspend immediately rather than asking each application for permission.
; Parameter #3: Pass 1 instead of 0 to disable all wake events.
DllCall("PowrProf\SetSuspendState", "int", 0, "int", 0, "int", 0)

Answer (score -1):

Under windows7, check out the "shutdown" command from the cmd prompt.

Unfortunately, while it has hibernation as an option, it does not include "sleep"

Comment: This isnt a keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score -1):

create a shortcut .. put the location of the file as logoff.exe and name the shortcut whatever.. done.. right click shortcut go to properties.. change icon and pick an icon image for your shortcut.

and if you want it to be a hotkey.. then right click the shortcut and notice the hotkey box ... click it.. and then press a combination of keys.. bang.. done.. your welcome.

Comment: This is the same answer as provided by @Revolter: http://superuser.com/a/72807/23133

Answer (score -2):

Maybe it is buried in here somewhere or maybe I do not understand the request, but the logout part is easy.  Instead of using a keystroke or two, the easiest way is to create a shortcut with an icon on the screen you can call Logout User or whatever strikes your fancy.  The shortcut should simply contain C:\windows\system32\shutdown.exe /L /F  Double click on the icon and you are logged out.

Comment: This duplicates another answer and adds no new content. Please don't post an answer unless you actually have something new to contribute.