# log off quickly with keyboard

Tags: windows-7, windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there windows 7 keyboard shortcuts for Log Off and Standby?](https://superuser.com/questions/72789/are-there-windows-7-keyboard-shortcuts-for-log-off-and-standby)

How can I log off quickly using the keyboard in Windows 7?

Comment: Ctrl Alt Delete, down arrow key, enter?

Answer (score 4):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>

Comment: Nice, I like this one very fast...

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

<kbd>Win Key</kbd>, <kbd>RightArrow</kbd>, <kbd>RightArrow</kbd>, <kbd>L</kbd>

Note that that means to *tap* the Windows-logo key, not to *hold it* while pressing the other keys.

Comment: sorry it does't work ......

Comment: Weird, on my machine it goes straight to "Log Off", are you using an English version of Windows 7?  What does it actually do? Also, you don't need to hold down the Windows key, just tap them in the sequence...

Comment: I can confirm this works if done in sequence.

Comment: This really depends on the language used by your Windows installation. For example, to log out on a German version of Windows, you'll have to hit A rather than L. If in doubt, check which character is underlined in the entry responsible for logging off.