# Single key shortcut to minimize window?

Tags: windows-10

So i'm looking for a way to assign a specific key on my keyboard as a shortcut for minimizing all open windows. I know such shortcut is Wind + down arrow or + M, but I would like to use a single key for that command, like let's say I dedicate the Tab button for that. Is there any way or program that does that?

Comment: Also see https://superuser.com/questions/745052/how-to-remap-a-single-specific-key-to-a-windows-shorcut

Answer (score 0):

[AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/download/) can help assign a specific key to an action/shortcut

- Install AutoHotkey or extract the portable app to suitable location
- Create an AHK file - an empty text file with `.ahk` extension instead of `.txt` (I usually go to Desktop > Right click > New > AutoHotkey Script)
- Modify the following lines as needed and add to AHK file

  ```
  ; lines beginning with semicolon (;) and characters appearing after a semicolon are considered as comments and are not executed
  ; some common key modifiers are ! for ALT, ^ for CTRL, # for WIN, + for SHIFT

  Pause::#m
  ; this remaps the `Pause/Break` button to `Win + M` key combo
  ; pressing `Pause/Break` button simulates Win + M to minimize all windows and show desktop
  ```

Replace `Tab` instead of `Pause` in the above line if that is what you prefer, but `Pause` is a better option as it is less frequently used.

- Save the AHK file and run it in one of the following ways -

  - Move the file or create a shortcut to the file in startup folder `%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`, so that your remapped key are enabled every time you login, or
  - Create a new task in **Task Scheduler** for more customized triggers, or
  - Run the AHK file manually by double clicking on it whenever you need it.

Check AutoHotkey [help](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/AutoHotkey.htm) for more information on how to remap keys and change the AHK file to suit your needs.

For additional software recommendations, post a question on SE's [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) website.